# Unable to console.log an API response which works in another project

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-tutorial/blob/master/documentation/home.md) tutorial using [bitquery](https://bitquery.io/products/dex) API.

Basically, I want to call crypto data ( Open, high, low, close) and feed it into the tradingview charting library and display the chart.

Following the tradingview tutorial, I am trying to `console.log` the API results on the console as the first step.

I have coded this till now

`helpers.js`

```
export async function makeApiRequest() {
    console.log("API FUNCTION")
    try {
        const query = `
        {
        ethereum(network: bsc){
        dexTrades(options: {limit: 100, asc: "timeInterval.minute"},
        date: {since:"2020-11-01"}
        exchangeName: {is: "Pancake"},
        baseCurrency: {is: "0xbA2aE424d960c26247Dd6c32edC70B295c744C43"},
        quoteCurrency: {is: "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"}){
        timeInterval {
        minute(count: 1)
        }
        baseCurrency {
        symbol
        address
        }
        baseAmount
        quoteCurrency {
        symbol
        address
        }
        quoteAmount
        trades: count
        quotePrice
        maximum_price: quotePrice(calculate: maximum)
        minimum_price: quotePrice(calculate: minimum)
        open_price: minimum(of: block get: quote_price)
        close_price: maximum(of: block get: quote_price)
        }}
        }`;

    res = await fetch('https://graphql.bitquery.io/', {
        method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'X-API-KEY': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
    mode: 'cors',
    });
    console.log(res)
    
    return res;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`API error: ${error.status}`);
    }
}
```

And this function is being called inside another file called `datafeed.js` like this.

```
import {
    makeApiRequest,
    generateSymbol,
    parseFullSymbol,
} from './helpers.js';


const lastBarsCache = new Map();

const configurationData = {
    supported_resolutions: ['1D', '5', '1W'],
    exchanges: [{
        value: 'Bitfinex',
        name: 'Bitfinex',
        desc: 'Bitfinex',
    },
    {
        value: 'Kraken',
        name: 'Kraken',
        desc: 'Kraken bitcoin exchange',
    },
    // {
    //  value: 'PancakeSwap',
    //  name: 'PancakeSwap',
    //  desc: 'PancakeSwap',
    // },
    ],
    symbols_types: [{
        name: 'crypto',
        value: 'crypto',
    }],
};

async function getAllSymbols() {
    const data = await makeApiRequest();
    console.log("/////////////"+data)
    return data;
}

export default {
    onReady: (callback) => {

        console.log('[onReady]: Method call');
        console.log(getAllSymbols())
        setTimeout(() => callback(configurationData));
    },

    searchSymbols: async (
        userInput,
        exchange,
        symbolType,
        onResultReadyCallback,
    ) => {
        console.log('[searchSymbols]: Method call');
        const symbols = await getAllSymbols();
        console.log(symbols)
};
```

This gives the following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: API error: undefined
    at makeApiRequest (helpers.js:48)
    at async getAllSymbols (datafeed.js:35)
```

However if you test out the api request on [bitquery online IDE](https://graphql.bitquery.io/ide) - it works

```
{
ethereum(network: bsc){
dexTrades(options: {limit: 100, asc: "timeInterval.minute"},
date: {since:"2020-11-01"}
exchangeName: {is: "Pancake"},
baseCurrency: {is: "0xbA2aE424d960c26247Dd6c32edC70B295c744C43"},
quoteCurrency: {is: "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"}){
timeInterval {
minute(count: 1)
}
baseCurrency {
symbol
address
}
baseAmount
quoteCurrency {
symbol
address
}
quoteAmount
trades: count
quotePrice
maximum_price: quotePrice(calculate: maximum)
minimum_price: quotePrice(calculate: minimum)
open_price: minimum(of: block get: quote_price)
close_price: maximum(of: block get: quote_price)
}}
}
```

What mistake am I making here? How do I get the data to `console.log` properly?

Update: I am able to see the data being fetched in the networks tab but it is still not being printed at console.

[image]

Errors in the browser console:

[image]

Comment: Do you see unsuccessful requests in Network tab when debugging it?

Comment: @NikitaChayka I updated the question. The API is being called successfully but not printing in console.

Answer (score 0):

Test QUERY (why named a response?) using Postman ... before coding ! Make sure all headers/elements are defined properly and if it works as expected.

There is a reason to name const `query` - graphql request requires field/arg `'query'` [and optional `'variables'`]

fragment ... `body: JSON.stringify({ response }),`
is a shortcut to `body: JSON.stringify({ response: response }),`
while `body: JSON.stringify({ query: response }),` is required. Renaming [your query] `'response'` to `'query'` can simplify it to `body: JSON.stringify({ query }),`.

Comment: Hi, I changed ```response``` to ```query``` and I am still getting the same error. Do I have to change something else?

Comment: `const res` means `res` can not be overwritten in next lines, console.log original res (before json parsing), take it step by step

Comment: I updated the code to what you said. I removed ```const``` and console logged res before json, I am still not getting any data in the console. I also put a screenshot of the errors.

Comment: promise logged? await json, too ... https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/#2-fetching-json ... or use axios